# Retina images issues

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

My question is next:
How to use pixel instead point for control?

For example I add to my project retina images (size 75, 45). In this case I create UIImage with a size 37pt, 22pt (and some pixel are lost)

I create puzzle game and very important that all the pixels match my mask.

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGRect` is a struct composed of `CGFloat` elements... So just set the sizes as 37.5 and 22.5 and you're done.  Why you would want to use odd-number sized retina images though is another question - are you not supporting non-retina devices?

Answer (score 2):

If the UIImageView size is 37x22, the image@2x size must be 74x44.

Comment: yes, this is correct. but in my but in my case very importent to compare coordinate all of image pixels.